Imbalanced time series dataset , sensor data retrieved from human locomotion, detect events but its not anomaly detection
For sensor data, retrieved from human location, time series data, I want to detect a particular event which occurs cyclically, but its not anomaly detection, its a part of regular locomotion,
I have tried LSTM (sequence to sequence), but I want expert advice on which machine learning, deep learning algorithm will be suitable for this task? I have thought of various options but to detect a frame precisely from many frames retrieved at about 100 frames/ second, can shapelet learning be useful here or any other suitable suggestion.
Thanks in advance

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
